# JNI: Inconsistent String behavior calling function in third party shared library

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am writing a JUnit test to verify following native method:

```
public native String mkString(byte[] bytes);
```

As part of native code, I invoke a function that returns `const char *` in third party shared library. I do a dlsym and get a function pointer to the third party function.

```
mkStringFn = (const char *(*)(char*, int)) dlsym(handle, "mkString");
```

On debugging I found that the while on the return statement in third party function `mkString`, the return variable always has the correct value.

But the I see that for the same input the return value that I get from invoking the function pointer is `""` sometimes and other times it has the right value.

This is how I call the function pointer

```
madeString = (* mkStringFn)((char *)bufferPtr, len); //madeString is sometimes empty (not NULL) and sometimes has the right value
```

I verified the bufferPtr and len parameter passed to function pointer is valid.

Any ideas as why this works only sometimes?

Comment: Having a hard time understand where the inconsistency is...  Does the third-party func sometimes just not return a good value?  Or does your native JNI function sometimes not return a good value to Java?

Comment: @Semhain I figured it out. The third party function was doing `std::string.c_str()`. The third party function must do a deep copy of `c_str()` and return it.

Comment: I believe that [java] and [jni] tags are irrelevant.